# Remote Server Security : iptables : give 4 minutes?

Tags: iptables, firewall

**Remote Server**:

I want to configure iptables to block all incoming traffic..

**BUT**.. **4 minutes after the system completely starts**

this way I can have **4 minutes to SSH and connect** to it
before I am locked out.

Best way to achieve(do) this ?

**Step 1** is probably:

```
 chkconfig iptables off
```

What is **Step 2**  ?

Comment: todo this you should create a script which will run after boot imediateli, like scripts in /etc/init.d scripts, in this script you will give the rules to pass to your iptables but befor this you should sleep 240 Seconds

Answer (score 3):

You can create a script which runs at system start so that it first sleeps for 4 minutes and then execute the desired iptables instruction.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
sleep 4m
/etc/init.d/iptables start
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

In order to execute it at system start, copy the script with proper permissions (`chmod +x yourscript.sh`) under /etc/init.d and update your rc, for example:

```
update-rc.d yourscript.sh defaults 100
```

Answer (score 0):

It is security-wise a better idea to have the firewall in place even before running any applications.

Therefore you are probably better of using `knockd`. This way you can setup a port knock sequence which opens the `ssh` port and closes it after a specified time.

A sample configuration can be:

```
/etc/knockd.conf
[options]
    logfile = /var/log/knockd.log

[opencloseSSH]
                   sequence      = 8081,8082,8083
                   seq_timeout   = 5
                   tcpflags      = syn
                   start_command = /usr/sbin/iptables -I IN_external_allow -i enp0s8 -s %IP% -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
                   cmd_timeout   = 15
                   stop_command  = /usr/sbin/iptables -D IN_external_allow -i enp0s8 -s %IP% -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

If you want to get in you can use something like:

```
nc -w 1 myhost 8081
nc -w 1 myhost 8082
nc -w 1 myhost 8083
ssh user@myhost
```

It is not necessary to have listeners for the mentioned ports since we check only on `syn` packets. It is necessary though to have the ports open on the outside firewall so the packets can reach your host. You can also use more common ports like 80,25,443 which are more likely to be open already.

This sequence must be completed within 5 seconds according to the configuration and after 15 seconds the port will be closed again. Existing sessions will remain open so this is safe to use.

See also http://www.zeroflux.org/projects/knock for details on how to configure this.